# SQL/Presto: right join bigger than original table due to NULL

Tags: sql, join, presto, outer-join

I need to right join 2 tables with 3 conditions but the resulting table is bigger than left or right table.

left_table a is like the following:

```
 capacity value  group_id   level_id    tags
 100       3      a            ab        
 120       5      a            afb       lala
 122       4      b            afg       hhh
 122       6      c            adfg
```

right table b is like the following: bigger than left table

```
 user      group_id    level_id    tags 
 adsf      a           ab          
 af        a           abf         df
 sf        a           afb         lala
 dsf       b           afg         hhh
 sdf       c           adfg
```

I want to append the value and capacity value to the right table b. I have used the following query but the resulting table is larger than the right table. I noticed that it is due to the NULL in tags in both the right and left tables, but i am wondering how to resolve this issue.

```
  select a.capacity, a.value, b.*
   from a
   right join b
   on a.group_id = b._group_id
   and a.level_id = b.level_id
   and a.tags = b.tags
```

Comment: would be easier to help if you add expected result and setup dbfiddle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I noticed that it is due to the NULL in tags in both the right and left tables

No, this is not the cause of duplicates.  In fact `NULL` values *fail* the comparison, so you will not get a match at all if either value is `NULL`.  That is, the row in `b` will be returned with `NULL` values for the columns from `a`.

If you want `NULL` values to match as being equal, then you need a `NULL`-safe comparison -- and Presto supports the SQL Standard `is not distinct from`.  I also strongly prefer `left join` over `right join`:

```
select a.capacity, a.value, b.*
from b left join
     a
     on a.group_id = b._group_id and
        a.level_id = b.level_id and
        a.tags is not distinct from b.tags;
```

If you are getting duplicates, it is because you have duplicates in `a`.  You can check for this using:

```
select group_id, level_id, tags, count(*)
from a
group by group_id, level_id, tags
having count(*) >= 2;
```